# Connection could not be established with host mailtrap.io [php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. #0]

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-mail

I am getting below error:

> Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com
> [php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known.
>
> ## 0]

My .env file looks like:

```
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
MAIL_PASSWORD=xxxxxxxx
#MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

My mail.php file inside config looks like:

```
/*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Mail Driver
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Laravel supports both SMTP and PHP's "mail" function as drivers for the
    | sending of e-mail. You may specify which one you're using throughout
    | your application here. By default, Laravel is setup for SMTP mail.
    |
    | Supported: "smtp", "mail", "sendmail", "mailgun", "mandrill",
    |            "ses", "sparkpost", "log"
    |
    */

    'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | SMTP Host Address
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may provide the host address of the SMTP server used by your
    | applications. A default option is provided that is compatible with
    | the Mailgun mail service which will provide reliable deliveries.
    |
    */

    'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | SMTP Host Port
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This is the SMTP port used by your application to deliver e-mails to
    | users of the application. Like the host we have set this value to
    | stay compatible with the Mailgun e-mail application by default.
    |
    */

    'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Global "From" Address
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | You may wish for all e-mails sent by your application to be sent from
    | the same address. Here, you may specify a name and address that is
    | used globally for all e-mails that are sent by your application.
    |
    */

    'from' => ['address' => null, 'name' => null],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | E-Mail Encryption Protocol
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify the encryption protocol that should be used when
    | the application send e-mail messages. A sensible default using the
    | transport layer security protocol should provide great security.
    |
    */

    'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | SMTP Server Username
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | If your SMTP server requires a username for authentication, you should
    | set it here. This will get used to authenticate with your server on
    | connection. You may also set the "password" value below this one.
    |
    */

    'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | SMTP Server Password
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may set the password required by your SMTP server to send out
    | messages from your application. This will be given to the server on
    | connection so that the application will be able to send messages.
    |
    */

    'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Sendmail System Path
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the "sendmail" driver to send e-mails, we will need to know
    | the path to where Sendmail lives on this server. A default path has
    | been provided here, which will work well on most of your systems.
    |
    */

    'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',

];
```

Surprisingly I am using this for last 6 months and it didn't error earlier but now when I uploaded my built again on staging I got this error.

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Comment: you did not provide mail credential in .env file all set null

Comment: signup at `https://mailtrap.io` and get username/password as said here : https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/introduction-to-mailtrap-a-fake-smtp-server-for-pre-production-testing--cms-23279

Comment: @Rishi I have updated my question. I am now using different details.

Comment: in your .env file add the following code and try again 
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls

Comment: we need to contact the hosting or domain provider and register the domain first. We need to register an A record and MX record of mail.yourdomain.com. The hosting team will guide you through the process. Once domain is registered, you need to wait 4 to 8 hrs for it to reflect.

Comment: 'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tsl'),
check Encytype tls,ssl or any other enctype

Answer (score 21):

This problem occurs when some changes have been made to files, specifically in .env file

Clear cache using artisan command

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

Clear config

```
php artisan config:clear
```

Restart your server

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

More: Try clearing browsers cache & cookies. Hope that works

Comment: Why didn't I think of that?!

Comment: This worked for me with the same issue - I would be keen to understand why this works - this resolved my issue but I don't understand why.

Comment: Actually it seems to be a temporary fix - issue is back for me.

Comment: this is the best solution. It work perfectly fine

Answer (score 5):

I just had this same problem.

It looks like the server is not able to ping the destination address.

I did a quick restart of my dev server and everything is back to normal.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I had this problem when im using the forgot password button (laravel breeze auth). can you help me?

Answer (score 4):

Use below code in `.env` file:

```
MAIL_ENCRYPTION= TLS
```

Try to clear `cache` , `config cache` , and `restart apache2`.

It works.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. It worked for me. Even though, restarting apache2 is not required. It seems Laravel 5.6.35 is smart enough to know the changes.

Comment: It worked for me. I just cleared the cache.

Answer (score 4):

.env

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=yourmail@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=yourmailIDpassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

config/mail.php

```
?php

return [

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Mail Driver
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Laravel supports both SMTP and PHP's "mail" function as drivers for the
| sending of e-mail. You may specify which one you're using throughout
| your application here. By default, Laravel is setup for SMTP mail.
|
| Supported: "smtp", "sendmail", "mailgun", "mandrill", "ses",
|            "sparkpost", "log", "array"
|
*/

'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| SMTP Host Address
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may provide the host address of the SMTP server used by your
| applications. A default option is provided that is compatible with
| the Mailgun mail service which will provide reliable deliveries.
|
*/

'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| SMTP Host Port
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This is the SMTP port used by your application to deliver e-mails to
| users of the application. Like the host we have set this value to
| stay compatible with the Mailgun e-mail application by default.
|
*/

'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Global "From" Address
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| You may wish for all e-mails sent by your application to be sent from
| the same address. Here, you may specify a name and address that is
| used globally for all e-mails that are sent by your application.
|
*/

'from' => [
    'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'hello@example.com'),
    'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Example'),
],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| E-Mail Encryption Protocol
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may specify the encryption protocol that should be used when
| the application send e-mail messages. A sensible default using the
| transport layer security protocol should provide great security.
|
*/

'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| SMTP Server Username
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| If your SMTP server requires a username for authentication, you should
| set it here. This will get used to authenticate with your server on
| connection. You may also set the "password" value below this one.
|
*/

'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),

'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Sendmail System Path
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When using the "sendmail" driver to send e-mails, we will need to know
| the path to where Sendmail lives on this server. A default path has
| been provided here, which will work well on most of your systems.
|
*/

'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Markdown Mail Settings
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| If you are using Markdown based email rendering, you may configure your
| theme and component paths here, allowing you to customize the design
| of the emails. Or, you may simply stick with the Laravel defaults!
|
*/

'markdown' => [
    'theme' => 'default',

    'paths' => [
        resource_path('views/vendor/mail'),
    ],
],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Log Channel
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| If you are using the "log" driver, you may specify the logging channel
| if you prefer to keep mail messages separate from other log entries
| for simpler reading. Otherwise, the default channel will be used.
|
*/

'log_channel' => env('MAIL_LOG_CHANNEL'),

];
```

app/Http/Controllers/yourcontroller.php

```
use App\Mail\sendMail;
use Mail;

public function fnmail($name,$password,$userid,$email)
{ 
  $data = array('name'=>$name, 'password' => $password, 'userid' => $userid);
  Mail::send('mail', $data, function($message) use ($name, $email) {
  $message->to($email, $name)
        ->subject('Subject');  //to redirect mail.blade.php page
  $message->from('YourMail@gmail.com','DoNotReply');
  });
}
```

then create folder under app.. the folder name is Mail
under this folder create sendMail.php file

sendMail.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class sendMail extends Mailable
{
use Queueable, SerializesModels;

/**
 * Create a new message instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    //
}

/**
 * Build the message.
 *
 * @return $this
 */
public function build()
{
    return $this->view('register'); //to redirect register page
}
}
```

then add resources/views/mail.blade.php

mail.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Mail Sending</title>
</head>
<body>
  <table align='center' style='height: 200px;width: 200px'>
   <tr><td colspan='2' bgcolor='skyblue' style='text-align: center;font-weight: 
  bold;size: 20px;'><label> Mail Check </label></td></tr>
   <tr bgcolor='#fff7e6'>
   <tr><td style='color: magenta;font-weight: bold;'><label><b>Your UserName:</b> 
 </label></td><td><b>{{$name}}</b></td></tr><br>
   <tr><td style='color: magenta;font-weight: bold;'><label><b>Your LoginID:</b> 
 </label></td><td><b>{{$userid}}</b></td></tr><br>
 <tr><td style='color: magenta;font-weight: bold;'><label><b>Your Password:</b> 
 </label></td><td><b>{{$password}}</b></td><br></tr>
</tr>
<tr><td colspan='2' align='center' bgcolor='orange'><a 
href='http://localhost/larashop/laravelProject/public/login'>
<button>Login</button></a></td></tr></table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

After modify your settings you need to run:
php artisan config:cache

Without those laravel will use old ones.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is actually a simple typo. In your .env file, change this:

`MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io`

to this:

`MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io`

I prepended the `smtp.` to the host

Answer (score 0):

## Edit and following this file: config / mail.php

```
'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),
'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'your mail host'),
'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', '465'),
'from' => [
        'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'Your email address'),
        'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Your email Name'),
'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'ssl'),
```

#### Don't touch for these two lines

```
'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),

'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
```

## Edit and following this file: /.env

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=your mail host
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=Your smtp email address
MAIL_PASSWORD=Your smtp password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl

MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=Your email address
MAIL_FROM_NAME="Your email Name"
```

## Use below artisan command.

## Clear cache using artisan command

php artisan config:clear

## Clear config

php artisan cache:clear

## Restart your server

sudo service httpd restart

It will be works! Enjoy your coding

Answer (score 0):

Edit `.env` file :

```
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
```

Edit `Config/mail.php` file :

```
'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),
```

`.env` and `mail.php` should both correspond to each other .

Answer (score 0):

This is because of Enctype is not given proper.
Check `config/mail.php` or `.env`

```
'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tsl'),
```

Encryption tsl,ssl or any other enctype. I also experienced with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check your internet connection first of all, because it also gives this exception.

Answer (score 0):

Generate a new key:

```
php artisan key:generate
```

In .env file:

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=[yourhost.domain]
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=[contact@yourhost.domain]
MAIL_PASSWORD=[yourpass]
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```