# sending verification email using Laravel 5.7 Email Verification from a server within a proxy network

Tags: php, laravel, symfony, laravel-5.7

My problem is different from  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41690219/connection-could-not-be-established-with-host-mailtrap-io-php-network-getaddres) , because i am getting this error due to proxy network. I am using **laravel 5.7** built-in **email verification**. i have configure it in the following way.

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=mygmail@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=mypass
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

This configuration works fine when i am connected to a non **proxy network**. when i change to a proxy network i am getting the following error

> "Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com [php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known.  #0]"

**How can i fix this issue for a proxy network?** i know my configuration is okay for non proxy network.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to add something like this to your `config/mail.php`

```
   return [
      'components' => [
        'mailer' => [
          'transport' => [
            'streamOptions' => [ 
              'ssl' => [ 
                'allow_self_signed' => true,
                'verify_peer' => false,
                'verify_peer_name' => false,
              ]
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ]

];
```

Comment: Did Try to clear cache, config cache, and restart apache?

Comment: Is SMTP set up on ? because it may be problem with DNS, firewall issues!!