# Laravel using wrong mail server

Tags: php, laravel

I recently took over a Laravel project and I'm in the process of setting up the development environment, which includes configuring the project to use a MySQL database. I've successfully configured most of the environment settings; however, I'm encountering an issue with the email confirmation feature. Despite making changes to the .env file to point to the correct mail server, the application still seems to be attempting to use the mail server settings from the previous project. This results in the following error message:

```
Connection could not be established with host previous.group.mailserver.com :stream_socket_client(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: The specified host is unknown.
```

I also changed the all the uses of Mail:send to use my development email:

```
 Mail::send($view, $mail_data, function ($message) use ($mail_data) {
            $message->to($mail_data['receiver_mail'], $mail_data['receiver_name'] . " " . $mail_data['receiver_surname'])->bcc('X', 'X')->subject('Confirmation Mail');
        });
```

mail.php

```
<?php
return [
    'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),
    'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),
    'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
    'from' => [
        'address' => 'myGmail@gmail.com',
        'name' => 'development email',
    ],

    'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
    'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
    'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
    'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
];
```

.env

```
APP_NAME=X
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=X
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http:http://localhost

UNIQUE_SERVER_URL=X/

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=X
MAIL_PASSWORD=X
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl


DATABASE=X
DATABASE_USERNAME=X
DATABASE_PASSWORD=X
```

composer.json

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.0.0",
        "barryvdh/laravel-cors": "^0.11.2",
        "fideloper/proxy": "~3.3",
        "laravel/framework": "5.5.*",
        "laravel/tinker": "~1.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "filp/whoops": "~2.0",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~6.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "ThekRe\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": [
            ]
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "allow-plugins": {
            "kylekatarnls/update-helper": true
        }
    }
}
```

i also followed the instructions from similar problems but without success:

[Connection could not be established with host mailtrap.io [php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. #0]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41690219/connection-could-not-be-established-with-host-mailtrap-io-php-network-getaddres)

Comment: Have you tried a `php artisan config:clear` to clear the configuration cache? In `php artisan tinker`, what does `config('mail')` output?

Comment: that outputs the credentials of the previous group but why? i also did `php artisan config:cache` before

Comment: Frankly, I'd suspect you're editing the wrong `.env` or that your settings are being overridden by configuration at the webserver level or something.

Comment: valid and very interesting approach, but what is interesting is that when i change the APP_URL it does change the actual url. I added the composer.jsonto the edit which might give some more info?

Comment: even if i do `php artisan config:clear` and after `php tinker` => config('mail') i would expect it to be empty or null or smth, but its still filled with the previous information

Answer (score 0):

You are using Gmail there's rules before using it:

https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en

Login to your gmail account and under **My account** > **Sign In And Security** > Sign In to google, **enable two step verification**, then you can generate app password, and you can use that app password in **.env** file.

```
....
MAIL_PASSWORD=your generated password
...
```

I suggest to use [mailtrap](https://mailtrap.io/) it easy to use and good for local tests

Comment: While true there's special things you have to do with Gmail, OP still shouldn't be getting `previous.group.mailserver.com` in their error messages. They'd be getting *different* errors.

Comment: i tried it and still get the same error as mentioned in the question

Comment: Okay, are you testing locally or on some servers EC2, centos ?

Comment: im using xamp where i use apache and sql